# How to use defined variables from ngOnInit() in another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular5

I'm new to angular 5. I'm using jquery Rate Yo pluging for rating in anngular 5 website. where I called rating plugin in `ngOnInit()` and it's working fine. The value of clicking star is storing in `this.amb`,`this.clean`,`this.serv`,`this.comf`. These all values are showing in console. I want to use this values with my `API` which is on Submit button but there value of these variables getting undefined. So how to get these value on my `onSubmit()` function.? Please help.

```
ngOnInit() {
    $(function () { 
        $("#ambience").rateYo({
          starWidth: "18px",
          fullStar: true,
          halfStar: false,
          onSet: function (rating, rateYoInstance) { 

            this.amb = rating;
            console.log(this.amb);
          },              
        });

      });
      $(function () { 
        $("#serviceq").rateYo({
          starWidth: "18px",
          fullStar: true,
          halfStar: false,
          onSet: function (rating, rateYoInstance) { 

            this.serv = rating;
            console.log(this.serv);
          },              
        });

      });
      $(function () { 
        $("#clean").rateYo({
          starWidth: "18px",
          fullStar: true,
          halfStar: false,
          onSet: function (rating, rateYoInstance) { 

            this.clean = rating;
            console.log(this.clean);
          },              
        });

      });
      $(function () { 
        $("#comfort").rateYo({
          starWidth: "18px",
          fullStar: true,
          halfStar: false,
          onSet: function (rating, rateYoInstance) { 

            this.comf = rating;
            console.log(this.comf);
          },              
        });

      });   
   }

      onSubmit() {       
             this.common.createAPIService('api/contact/Feedback?FirstName=' + this.formGroup.controls.FirstName.value + '&LastName=' + this.formGroup.controls.LastName.value + '&Address=' + this.formGroup.controls.Address.value + '&City=' + this.formGroup.controls.City.value + '&Cinema=' + this.formGroup.controls.Cinema.value + '&Pincode=' + this.formGroup.controls.Picode.value + '&Phone=' + this.formGroup.controls.Mobile.value + '&Email=' + this.formGroup.controls.Email.value + '&Comments=' + this.formGroup.controls.Comments.value + '&ServiceQuality='+ this.serv +'&Ambience=' + this.amb +'&Cleanliness='+ this.clean + '&Comfort='+ this.comf,'').subscribe((result: any) => {
        //alert(result.Message);
      this.common.ShowNotification("FeedBack", result.Message, "info");
        this.onReset();
    })
}
```

Comment: Please don't use JQuery in you Angular project

Comment: Yes. I'm new to angular. Angular rating plugins is not working. Don't know why. That's why I used these

Comment: You can use instance variable, Angular component is basically typescript class using instance variable you can access in all functions. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html. And angular bootstrap has rating component https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/rating/examples#basic

Answer (score 0):

It's because you use traditional functions and not arrow function

**Using Arrow function**

```
ngOnInit() {
    $(() => { 
        $("#ambience").rateYo({
          starWidth: "18px",
          fullStar: true,
          halfStar: false,
          onSet: function (rating, rateYoInstance) { 

            this.amb = rating;
            console.log(this.amb);
          },              
        });

      });
      $(() => { 
        $("#serviceq").rateYo({
          starWidth: "18px",
          fullStar: true,
          halfStar: false,
          onSet: function (rating, rateYoInstance) { 

            this.serv = rating;
            console.log(this.serv);
          },              
        });

      });
      $(() => { 
        $("#clean").rateYo({
          starWidth: "18px",
          fullStar: true,
          halfStar: false,
          onSet: function (rating, rateYoInstance) { 

            this.clean = rating;
            console.log(this.clean);
          },              
        });

      });
      $(() => { 
        $("#comfort").rateYo({
          starWidth: "18px",
          fullStar: true,
          halfStar: false,
          onSet: function (rating, rateYoInstance) { 

            this.comf = rating;
            console.log(this.comf);
          },              
        });

      });   
   }

      onSubmit() {       
             this.common.createAPIService('api/contact/Feedback?FirstName=' + this.formGroup.controls.FirstName.value + '&LastName=' + this.formGroup.controls.LastName.value + '&Address=' + this.formGroup.controls.Address.value + '&City=' + this.formGroup.controls.City.value + '&Cinema=' + this.formGroup.controls.Cinema.value + '&Pincode=' + this.formGroup.controls.Picode.value + '&Phone=' + this.formGroup.controls.Mobile.value + '&Email=' + this.formGroup.controls.Email.value + '&Comments=' + this.formGroup.controls.Comments.value + '&ServiceQuality='+ this.serv +'&Ambience=' + this.amb +'&Cleanliness='+ this.clean + '&Comfort='+ this.comf,'').subscribe((result: any) => {
        //alert(result.Message);
      this.common.ShowNotification("FeedBack", result.Message, "info");
        this.onReset();
    })
}
```

For a good rating component : https://primefaces.org/primeng/#/rating

Comment: Where have you defined your variables?

Comment: Yes. In my above code i just replace  $(function () this to  $(() => {

Comment: I definded these serv:any; comf:any;
    amb:any;
    clean:any; above constructor